# Vue.js & CTK Range Time Picker. How it works?

Tags: vue.js

i just discovered CTK Date Time Picker but i can only run  the Date Time Picker.
I can't find in the documentation how to run Range Date Picker

This is a simple code of the component:

```
<div id="app">
  <vue-ctk-date-time-picker 
  label="Hello World!" 
  v-model="date" 
 
 id=RangeDatePicker
  label="Select date Range"
  format='YYYY-MM-DD'
  formatted='ll'
  range=true
   only-date=true
    dark="false">
                            
                                   
  </vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
 
</div>
```

Example of Range Date Picket :

https://chronotruck.github.io/vue-ctk-date-time-picker/

Documentation:

https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker

If someone use CTK Date Picker and can help. It would be great. Thanks.

Comment: did you find the answer? I'm having the same problem... =/

Answer (score 2):

I just build a working example on codePen:

https://codepen.io/bozieu/pen/vPWjdP?editors=1111

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-ctk-date-time-picker@2.0.6/dist/vue-ctk-date-time-picker.css">
<div id="app">
    <vue-ctk-date-time-picker label="Hello World!" v-model="value" :range="true">
    </vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-ctk-date-time-picker@2.0.6/dist/vue-ctk-date-time-picker.umd.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('vue-ctk-date-time-picker', window['vue-ctk-date-time-picker']);
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data () {
            return {
                value: null
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I want the date only, and not the time, as the question showed on the params -> ```only-date=true```. Your example shows the time. It doesn't answer the question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example. Range automatically shows only date and the format parameter controls the selected date format, in this case:

> {"start":"20191202","end":"20191211"}

I found the date picker to be the most flexible and customizable. I use it both for date and date&time.
This instance happens to be inline as I hide and show it when a radio button selects the Range option.

Note the colon in front of each property and the single quotes inside double quotes for string property values.

Hope this helps you.

```
          <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
            v-model="dateRange"
            :inline="true"
            :range="true"
            :color="'var(--C_TRUEGREEN)'"
            :custom-shortcuts="shortcuts"
            :format="'YYYYMMDD'"
            :formatted="'MM/DD/YYYY'"
            :label="'Select date'"
          >
          </vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
```